# Azure Function in dotnet core

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to port my C# code over to dotnet core so that my Function would be able to run cross-platform (if it had to).

I'm currently struggling to find Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host for core. Has that not been implemented yet? Which currently means there's no logging.

Are there other things that currently don't work in core?

Comment: Also, is there anything else currently documented that needs to be changed in order for Azure Functions to execute a .net-core binary?

Comment: A .Net Core 2.0 DLL is compatible With .Net 4.6.1  See http://immo.landwerth.net/netstandard-versions/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` NuGet version `1.0.6`, you will get `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host` with it, including the logger. It is compatible to .NET Core.

See a working example in [this repo](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/CSharpHttpCore).